# Unity load medias from folder and display on RawImage

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, resources, media-player

I am trying to create a media player in Unity that reads all media files from a static folder and plays trough all medias (images static duration, videos for the length of the video). First I am trying to get it to work with just images.

I'm very new with Unity and not good with C#. I'm able to get all media file sources (images) to an array but next I need to convert them to a texture and place on the RawImage -component. I'm stuck with this part.

If I have the src (ex. C:\medias\img1.jpg) then how could I place this as a image on the RawImage -component?

My code ->

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEditor;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\medias");
        string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".JPG", ".jpeg", ".JPEG", ".png", ".PNG", ".ogg", ".OGG" };
        FileInfo[] info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
        Debug.Log (info[0]);
        // Logs C:\medias\img1.jpg
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First I am trying to get it to work with just images.
>
> I'm very new with Unity and not good with C#. I'm able to get all
>   media file sources (images) to an array but next I need to convert
>   them to a texture and place on the RawImage -component. I'm stuck with
>   this part.

You are looking for the [`Texture2D.LoadImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html) function. It converts image bytes to Texture2D then you can assign that Texture2D to the RawImage.

You have to ask new question about how to do this with Videos. That's much more complicated.

```
public RawImage rawImage;
Texture2D[] textures = null;

//Search for files
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\medias");
string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".JPG", ".jpeg", ".JPEG", ".png", ".PNG", ".ogg", ".OGG" };
FileInfo[] info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();

//Init Array
textures = new Texture2D[info.Length];


for (int i = 0; i < info.Length; i++)
{
    MemoryStream dest = new MemoryStream();

    //Read from each Image File
    using (Stream source = info[i].OpenRead())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            dest.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }

    byte[] imageBytes = dest.ToArray();

    //Create new Texture2D
    Texture2D tempTexture = new Texture2D(2, 2);

    //Load the Image Byte to Texture2D
    tempTexture.LoadImage(imageBytes);

    //Put the Texture2D to the Array
    textures[i] = tempTexture;
}

//Load to Rawmage?
rawImage.texture = textures[0];
```